# WCF does not terminate call to Client

Tags: azure, wcf, virtual-machine

I have a problem with a WCF service which is hosted on a Windows 2016 VM in Azure running in IIS 10.

The service is basically a test service where I put in the operationContract a Thread.Sleep (timer) and the duration is sent as a parameter defined in the operationContract.

The problem is that specifying a sleep duration of up to 4.2 seconds runs without problems, but if I call the service specifying 5 seconds to run. The task process ends at 5 seconds, with the code above, the internal logger notifies me that I am done but for some reason WCFTestClient is still waiting for a response and continues to wait until the configured timeout is reached. In this case I have my Receive_timeout and Send 10 minutes on both sides in the service config and in the client config.

As proof I created a local environment in my network, mounting the service on a server, and here after 5 minutes or even a 9 minute test test client behaves as expected.

```
[OperationContract]
    public void TestServiceTimeout (int timer)
    {
        try
        {
            log.Info("Start test Service");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timer);
            log.Info("End test srervices");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error($"An error ocurred. Details: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Web.Config IIS

```
<binding name="Control.ws.sTest.customBinding0" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" 
        sendTimeout="00:20:00">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
```

WCFTestClient Config

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_sFacturacion" sendTimeout="00:10:00" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:60000/ws/sFacturacion.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_sFacturacion"
            contract="sFacturacion" name="BasicHttpBinding_sFacturacion" />
    </client>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this if you run WCFTestClient on the VM hosting the WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

WCF will not shut down the client actively, even if the server is offline, the client will catch the communication exception after the configured timeout is reached. 
Please refer to the below definition of the Timeout settings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.